# How I can save user's actions logging to DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, serverless, aws-appsync, aws-elasticsearch

I have project on the AWS web services. I use AppSync and serverless. How I can save user action logging for all mutation and query ? For example: user create new Item, I need write action to DB I need save all user's actions.

Comment: You could use dynamo streams and lambda triggers like [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried CloudTrail yet? It records all the user activity.

If that is something that is insufficient for your use case then try using a Lambda to write to the DynamoDb.

Within Lambda there are options to set triggers which could initiate a write to DynamoDB

If you write more about your use case then may be you could get more help in the exact approach that could be used

Comment: CloudTrail doesn't have Api request :( I need to logging user's API(appsync mutation and query) calls.

Comment: Just trying yo understand your use case. So you want to move CloudTrail Data to DynamoDB?